# Django migration large file

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-migrations

I am trying to do a makemigration on a large `models.py` file with almost a hundred classes. The command `manage.py makemigrations <app_name>` is giving me a `MemoryError`. I think it has to do with the large `models.py` file.

```
File "/home/venv_two/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/core/management/commands/makemigrations.py", line 231, 
in write_migration_files migration_string = writer.as_string()

File "/home/venv_two/local/lib/python2.7/site- 
packages/django/db/migrations/writer.py", line 166, in as_string
items["operations"] = "\n".join(operations) + "\n" if operations else ""
MemoryError
```

Comment: To find out if the number of classes is a problem, you could remove half the classes from the models file and try to see if you still get the error.

Comment: Removing a number of classes and running multiple makemigrations does not help because Django makemigrations looks back at previous migration files and, consequently taking up memory resources. The result is the same as the original run with all the classes intact.